# Parcel Data Transfer on onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I have problem with parcel data transfer. I don't know how to 
transfer object parcelable to onActivityResult.
DreamDatabase implements Parcelable.

MyDreams.class

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_addream:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddDreamActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CREATE);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE) {
                    DreamDatabase dreamDatabase = data.getData()
                    myDreamAdapter.addDream(dreamDatabase);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dreamd was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

AddDreams.class

```
if (!hasError) {
                    String selectDreamString = selectDreamTextView.getText().toString();
                    DreamDatabase dreamDatabase = new DreamDatabase(dreamTitleString, dreamDescriptionString, getCurrentDate(), selectDreamString);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("dream", dreamDatabase);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    super.finish();
                }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block:

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE) {
                    DreamDatabase dreamDatabase = data.getData()
                    myDreamAdapter.addDream(dreamDatabase);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dreamd was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Should be changed to:

```
DreamDatabase dreamDatabase = data.getParcelableExtra("dream");
...
```